# How to identify different arrays between two jsons

Tags: php

I found different answers about comparing two arrays but none worked in my case. I have two Jsons an Old.json with old values saved and New.json with new values to be saved. I just want to save in Old what's new in New.json that I do not already have in Old.json

OLD.JSON

```
{
    "jogos-da-copa": [
        "/videos/291856.html",
        "/videos/291830.html",
        "/videos/291792.html",
        "/videos/291759.html",
        "/videos/291720.html",
        "/videos/291705.html"
    ],
    "apresentacao": [
        "/videos/2926328.html",
        "/videos/67.html",
        "/videos/36.html",
        "/videos/3.html"
    ]
}
```

NEW.JSON

```
{
    "jogos-da-copa": [
        "/videos/291887.html",
        "/videos/291856.html",
        "/videos/291830.html",
        "/videos/291792.html",
        "/videos/291759.html",
        "/videos/291720.html",
        "/videos/291705.html"
    ],
    "apresentacao": [
        "/videos/2926385.html",
        "/videos/2926328.html",
        "/videos/67.html",
        "/videos/36.html",
        "/videos/3.html"
    ]
}
```

I used this code but it is not displaying the differences

```
$old1 = json_decode(file_get_contents('old.json'), true);
$new2 = json_decode(file_get_contents('new.json'), true);
$test = [];

foreach ($old1 as $key1 => $olds1) {

    foreach ($new2 as $key2 => $news2 ) {

    $test[] = array_diff($olds1, $news2);

    }

}

var_dump($test);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below function and pass your old and new array to the argument

```
$old = json_decode($old_json, true);
$new = json_decode($new_json, true);

$array_keys = array_keys( array_merge( $old, $new));

$dif_array = array();
foreach($array_keys as $key)
{
    if(array_key_exists($key, $old) && array_diff($new[$key], $old[$key])){
        $dif_array[$key] = array_diff($new[$key], $old[$key]);
    } else {
        $dif_array[$key] = $new[$key];
    }
}

$final_array = array_merge_recursive($old, $dif_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

From [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) docs:

*Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.*

In your case, the new array contains all the values from the old array. To get a list of all the new values, you need to switch your arguments around:

```
$old1 = json_decode(file_get_contents('old.json'), true);
$new2 = json_decode(file_get_contents('new.json'), true);
$test = [];

foreach ($old1 as $key1 => $olds1) {

    foreach ($new2 as $key2 => $news2 ) {
        $test[] = array_diff($news2, $olds1);
    }

}

var_dump($test);
```

Comment: That way it also does not work it returns all values not only the difference